# Spring Security and Cognito : CustomAuthenticationProvider never invoked

Tags: spring-security, amazon-cognito, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to make a project with APIs with cognito authentication. For this, I need a CustomAuthenticationProvider to get user's roles from another microservice. But it is never invoked.

application.yml

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          cognito:
            clientId: xxxx
            clientSecret: xxxxx
            scope: openid
            redirectUriTemplate: "http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/cognito"
            clientName: xxxx
        provider:
          cognito:
            issuerUri: https://cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/us-west-2_xxxx
            usernameAttribute: cognito:username
```

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose:5.3.3.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-tx:5.2.7.RELEASE'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

securityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity( securedEnabled = true )
@ComponentScan( "com.project" )
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure ( final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth ) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider( this.authProvider );
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure ( final HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception {
        http.cors();

        http.csrf().disable();

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers( "/public/**" )
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers( "/user/**" )
                .hasRole( "USER" )
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Client()
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider( new CustomAuthenticationProvider() );

    }


}
```

CustomAuthenticationProvider

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate ( final Authentication authentication ) throws AuthenticationException {
        String userName = authentication.getName();
        System.out.println( userName );
        return new AWSAuthentication( userName, Arrays.asList( new SimpleGrantedAuthority( "ROLE_USER" ) ) );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports ( Class<?> authentication ) {
        return authentication.equals( AWSAuthentication.class );
    }

}
```

No error occur, only 403.

I saw this [example](https://medium.com/@arjunsk/resource-server-with-cognito-b7fbfbee0155), but it is deprecated.

Could anyone help me with some clue or example?

Comment: can you try to remove `.authenticationProvider(new CustomAuthenticationProvider())`. using `auth.authenticationProvider( this.authProvider );` should be enough

Comment: I did it, but continues with the same problem.

Comment: for which endpoint do you get 403 and can you succesfully login with AWS Cognito as first step? The following guide might help you setting up Spring Security and AWS Cognito properly: https://rieckpil.de/thymeleaf-oauth2-login-with-spring-security-and-aws-cognito/

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem adapting the code of this [lib](https://github.com/IxorTalk/ixortalk.aws.cognito.jwt.security.filter) to my necessity.

Comment: Hi Walter, I guess I'm trying to do the same thing here, do you have any example?

Comment: You can get the code of the lib I linked above as example. That's what I did.